# redirecting out put in a nested for loop

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

Im writing a simple script which works fine an displays the output to the screen. I would like to redirect that otuput to a file named after one of the variables but it keeps creating empty files with no ouput.

basically, I want to see the crontab entries for each user listed and redirect the output to a file where the  name of the file is the server name.

---

```
servers=`cat hosts.txt`
for i in $servers;
do
    echo $i
    users=`ssh $i cut -d ":" -f1 /etc/passwd`
    for n in $users
    do
        crontab -u $n -l > $i-test.txt
    done 
done
```

---

the file `<servername>-test.txt` gets created but the output from `crontab -u $n -l`  is not there, but is displayed on the screen.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You're running crontab on your main machine, not your server machines. Was it intended to be so?

Comment: Despite what the manual says for the `-l` option, can you check if `crontab` is actually writing to standard error instead? `crontab -u $n -l 2> $i-text.txt`.

Comment: Actually, thats wrong, its suppose to pull the users from /etc/passwd on each box and and run crontab -u $user -l  and out put this info to a textfile, name servername.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the contents of `hostname-text.txt` each time, and when the last user is a system account or other user without a crontab, the file will be empty.

Meanwhile, you'll be getting the error output for crontab, "no crontab for ...", for all users since this is printed to stderr.

The fix depends on what you want to do. Here's a small fix that redirects the entire loop, along with error information:

```
servers=`cat hosts.txt`
for i in $servers;
do
    echo $i
    users=`ssh $i cut -d ":" -f1 /etc/passwd`
    for n in $users
    do
        echo "Crontab for $n:"
        ssh "$i" crontab -u $n -l 
        echo
    done > "$i-test.txt" 2>&1
done
```

This would give you a file `myhost-test.txt` containing something like

```
Crontab for user:
0 * * * * foo
0 4 * * * bar

Crontab for mysql:
no crontab for mysql
```

(This ignores spacing, quoting and efficiency concerns in favor of sticking closely to your code.)